# asp.net provide feedback for a long running process while parsing an xml file

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, callback, websocket

I've been looking for a some direction for my problem, and I found a couple of good things but nothing really clear and conclusive to teach me how to develop what I need.

I'm parsing a big XML file (about 9000 lines), each line of this file contains instruction for my program, and I want to inform my user what is happening behind the curtains for each line being processed.

Let's say the current line is telling me to create a file, so I will output "Operation #3940 - Creating File", the next line says to delete a file so I will "Operation #3941 - Deleting File", and so on.... for each line I will output what I'm doing.

This should produce something like this:

```
**Processing XML:**

Operation #1 - Checking file
Operation #2 - Updating file
Operation #3 - Renaming file
Operation #4 - Updating file
Operation #6 ...
Operation #7 ...
...
...
...
...
Operation #9000 - Closing XML

**Processing Completed!**
```

The challenge here? once the user hit the button to launch the processing of the xml file, my page updates the user with the continuous feedback without a page refresh, keeping intact what is in the page and adding the current status, is there any way to do this? can anybody show an example? So far I found things related to callback and async but no good example, just weird progress bars in very complex codes!

Comment: You could continuously poll the server using Ajax. Or you could push data to the client using web sockets. By the way, is this Web Forms or Mvc?